# Run "mvn clean install" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

Title says it all.

I want to run the console command `mvn clean install` on my project in question *directly* in Eclipse, not from the command line.

It would just be more convenient for me to do this, as I already have the project open in Eclipse.  It would save me time if I would not have to navigate to the folder in Windows Explorer.

Not a big deal if I can't do this... but can I?  And if so, how?

It would be great if I could just right click my project, then click "mvn clean install" from the context menu.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I use eclipse STS, so the maven plugin comes pre-installed. However, if you aren't using STS (Springsource Tool Suite), you can still install the m2Eclipse plugin. Here is the link:

http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

Once you have this installed, you should be able to run all the maven commands. To do so, from the package explorer, you would right click on either the maven project or the **pom.xml** in the maven project, highlight **Run As**, then click **Maven Install**.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 38):

Run a custom maven command in Eclipse as follows:

1. Right-click the maven project or pom.xml
2. Expand **Run As**
3. Select **Maven Build...**
4. Set *Goals* to the command, such as: `clean install -X`

Note: Eclipse prefixes the command with `mvn` automatically.

Comment: Better this approach, because is possible specify extra options/configurations prior to execute the goal

Comment: -X , is for debug.

Comment: Perfect. straightforward.

Answer (score 6):

You can create external command Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configuration...

It will be available under Run -> External Tools and can be run using shortcuts.

Comment: You can also create a Maven Build from the normal Run configuration menu if you have a Maven plugin installed.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on pom.xml, Run As, you should see the list of m2 options if you have Maven installed, you can select Maven Clean from there

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open command prompt inside your eclipse, this can be a useful approach to link cmd with eclipse.

You can follow this link to get the steps in detail with screenshots.
[How to use cmd prompt inside Eclipse ?](http://idiotechie.com/how-to-use-cmd-prompt-inside-eclipse/)

I'm quoting the steps here:

**Step 1:**  Setup a new External Configuration Tool

In the Eclipse tool go to Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configurations option.

**Step 2:** Click New Launch Configuration option in Create, manage and run configuration screen

**Step 3:** New Configuration screen for configuring the command prompt

**Step 4:** Provide configuration details of the Command Prompt in the Main tab

**Name:** Give any name to your configuration (Here it is Command_Prompt)
**Location:** Location of the CMD.exe in your Windows
**Working Directory:** Any directory where you want to point the Command prompt

**Step 5:** Tick the check box Allocate console
This will ensure the eclipse console is being used as the command prompt for any input or output.

**Step 6:** Click Run and you are there!! You will land up in the C: directory as a working directory

Answer (score 0):

Just found a convenient workaround:

Package Explorer > Context Menu (for specific project) > StartExplorer > Start Shell Here

This opens the cmd line for my project.

Unless someone can provide me a better answer, I will accept my own for now.