# Spring Boot Banking Project: Log In Page Not Showing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating a log in page, which will allow the user to sign in. However, when I try to visit http://localhost:8080/index via Google Chrome, I am just seeing "index," nothing else. But it is supposed to display the log in page that I created using HTML and Bootstrap.

Here are the codes of HomeController.java

```
package com.userFront.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "redirect:/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public @ResponseBody String index() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

You can find all the project files here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fxTWDo_3_iaS4zaav60KaT9OvB-kSjv6

**Update:1**
I have been advised to remove @ResponseBody from the method index(). But when I do that, the following problem occurs:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Dec 11 17:52:53 
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Circular view path [index]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/index] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

**Update 2:**
Here is the latest version of HomeController class, which I modify based on the advise I receive from @vtx:

```
package com.userFront.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String home() {
            return "redirect:/index";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/welcome")
        public String index() {
            return "index";
        }

    }
```

But now, a new error occurs, which says:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Dec 11 18:52:41 
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

**Update 3:** As advised by @vtx, I have tried to clean install Maven. However, the following error occurs:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building UserFront 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ userFront ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 30 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ userFront ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to C:\Users\Kanon\eclipse-workspace\UserFront\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.606 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-11T23:31:14+06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/227M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project userFront: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

**Update 4:** As suggested by @vtx, I have performed clean installation of Maven.
I have followed stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/… and stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/…. Maven is installed cleanly without any error. But now, I am getting "Circular view path" error.

**Update 5:** @vtx suggested me to use the following code again:

```
package com.userFront.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String home() {
            return "redirect:/index";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/welcome")
        public String index() {
            return "index";
        }

    }
```

But once again, I am getting the following error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Dec 12 00:27:42 
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

It's getting incredibly frustrating. But I will not give up!

Comment: use `"redirect:/index.html"` instead of `"redirect:/index"`

Comment: Work through a good Spring Boot Web Starter Tutorial. You need a view definition to be stored in the correct location - e.g. a Thymeleaf file or a Freemarker Template. If there is no "index.ftl" or similar (in the correct location), Spring Boot does not know what to display as "index", and just invokes the controller again.
Also, you should show your SecurityConfigurator class, which you must use to register your form login page.

Comment: @ Florian Albrecht : spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependency is available in pom and index.html is available in resource-templates location..so the viewresolver is capable of finding index.html file if we return simply index

Comment: @YCF_L Still doesn't work. Showing the same thing.

Comment: You don't have a mapping for /index. Change `@RequestMapping("/welcome")` to  `@RequestMapping("/index")`.

Comment: @Christian After changing that, I am getting "circular view path" error. There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Circular view path [index]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/index] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

Answer (score 0):

The `@ResponseBody` annotation tells a controller that the object returned is automatically serialized into `JSON` and passed back into the `HttpResponse` object.

You should remove `@ResponseBody`

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
```

I was able to run your code successfully with the changes mentioned above, I didn't face any circular path error or 404.

**Proof**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "redirect:/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public  String index() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

[image]

```
017-12-11 21:15:07.835  INFO 4840 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-12-11 21:15:07.843  INFO 4840 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-11 21:15:07.843  INFO 4840 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-11 21:15:07.844  INFO 4840 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-11 21:15:07.844  INFO 4840 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-11 21:15:08.311  INFO 4840 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6c9f5c0d: startup date [Mon Dec 11 21:15:04 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-11 21:15:08.409  INFO 4840 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/index]}" onto public java.lang.String com.userFront.controller.HomeController.index()
2017-12-11 21:15:08.410  INFO 4840 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.userFront.controller.HomeController.home()
2017-12-11 21:15:08.416  INFO 4840 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-12-11 21:15:08.416  INFO 4840 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-12-11 21:15:08.464  INFO 4840 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-11 21:15:08.464  INFO 4840 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-11 21:15:08.516  INFO 4840 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

**Please do mvn clean install. Hope that will help**

Comment: @john  exactly ...try  localhost:8080/welcome or  localhost:8080/userFront/welcome on chrome

Comment: Can you update the question with latest HomeController  class

Comment: @RequestMapping("/index") and index.html are different. so you can change it. in updated version you dont have any path named /index so I advised you to change redirect:/index to redirect:/welcome. it wont resolve your issue. because you are invoking localhost:8080/UserFront/welcome. It is mapped to @RequestMapping("/welcome")

Comment: @john , I was able to run your code by simply removing the Responsebody. I didn't change anything else.

Comment: Please do mvn clean install. hope it will help. because its worked for me without any issues

Comment: How can I clean install the maven? I have followed this video, but it doesn't work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cR9sqUrJwBU

Comment: right click on project and run as maven clean and then run as maven install..follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793895/run-mvn-clean-install-in-eclipse

Comment: I used maven clean and maven install options. But it looks like it is not being installed correctly. I am going to post the errors in the updated description.

Comment: Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra

Comment: I have followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra.  Maven is installed cleanly without any error. But now, I am getting "Circular view path" error. It's incredibly frustrating.

Comment: Expand maven dependency view form project exploror  and check for thymeleaf decency.

Comment: There are multiple thymeleaf dependencies, including thymeleaf-spring-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar and thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: All of them are needed. just want to check maven worked fine. Now try to change     @RequestMapping("/index") to  @RequestMapping("/welcome") and invoke localhost:8080/welcome

Comment: 404 issue has occurred again. There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: I have tried all the way. its working for me, if you have any remote access tool I will be able to help you further

Comment: I am incredibly grateful to you. I never expected someone to help me in possibly all the ways. God bless you. It's mid night here. So,I need to go to bed now. I will come up with a remote access tool tomorrow.

Comment: Would you please tell me which remote software should I use? Which one do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I look at you last changes and see that you redirect to index but you don't have mapping for "/index".
Maybe you should do this

```
 @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "redirect:/welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
```

It will work but seemes not logic. 
Just write

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }
```

That's all to return you index page.
Make sure you have set you index.html page to src/main/resources/static folder If you didn't change default configurations spring boot will look there